# Data migration from SQL Server to Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration, sqlline

Using SQLLINES I am trying to migrate from SQL Server to Postgres.
http://www.sqlines.com/home

My problem is that the data once migrated (type `nvarchar` in SQL Server) is translated to `text` or `varchar` in Postgres and the data itself is impacted.

Example source data: `ordertask`

Target data

```
:o\000r\000d\000e\000r\000t\000a\000s\000k\000
```

the`\000` is added automatically to all `varchar` data after each character.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The string you see with the `\000`’s is simply the string you want, but it is encoded in UTF-16LE, Windows’ default character encoding, which is not supported by PostgreSQL.

You could store UTF-16LE-encoded strings in PostgreSQL as byte arrays, but you would lose all text manipulation functions which you probably need.

You should use one of many tools to convert from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 (PostgreSQL preferred encoding) before passing the strings to postgreSQL (on a linux command line, I would use `iconv` or `recode`; your mileage may vary).  Another option is to use a client which does the conversion for you (probably all Windows-based clients do).